# Write Custom Text on image for php

Tags: php

I would like to add custom text on shirt and other device. but i dont know where to tackle the custom aspect in the area of adding text and logo to the shirt.

Comment: so, you need to edit the image and add text over it. right?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php or http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: Yes, i want user to be able to add text and put their own logo on the image and they can send it to my database so i can see what they designed

Comment: You should start by building something. Break you app down into multiple small steps and take one step at a time. When/if you get stuck in something _specific_, come back, show us what you've tried, explain the issue and we might be able to help you. In it's current state, this question is _way_ to broad.

Comment: Thanks Magus Ericksson for the advice i will start up with the project and i will update you on the how the process is going so you can help me out on it. Thanks so much for this great advice..

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest libraries for working with images is Intervention.
(http://image.intervention.io/api/text)

From their website documentation:

```
// create Image from file
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');

// write text
$img->text('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.');

// write text at position
$img->text('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.', 120, 100);

// use callback to define details
$img->text('foo', 0, 0, function($font) {
  $font->file('foo/bar.ttf');
  $font->size(24);
  $font->color('#fdf6e3');
  $font->align('center');
  $font->valign('top');
  $font->angle(45);
});

// draw transparent text
$img->text('foo', 0, 0, function($font) {
  $font->color(array(255, 255, 255, 0.5))
});
```